# Better alternative to using Void for optional argument

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have an interface specifying method that takes a generic type as input which is used to create a URL.

```
interface UrlGenerator<T> {

    String prepareUrl( T input );

}
```

There is one implementation that doesn't need the parameter. It uses Void for generic type T.

```
class StaticUrlGenerator implements UrlGenerator<Void> {

    private final String url;

    public StaticUrlGenerator( String url ) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String prepareUrl( Void nothing ) {
        return url;
    }

}
```

The StaticUrlGenerator is awkward to use, as it requires null as an argument to the `prepareUrl` method.

I could lose the `input` parameter:

```
interface UrlGenerator<T> {

    String prepareUrl( T input );

}
```

Now I have to pass the required input to the implementing class in other way (in constructor). This way I lose the stateless nature of the class, I have to recreate it with different constructor arguments every time I want to change the input.

```
class SchedulePageUrlGenerator implements UrlGenerator {

    public static final String QUERY_STRING_BASE = "?from=";

    private final String showingBaseUrl;
    private final LocalDate date;

    public SchedulePageUrlGenerator( String showingBaseUrl, LocalDate date ) {
        this.showingBaseUrl = showingBaseUrl;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String prepareUrl() {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
        String dateStr = fmt.print( date );
        return showingBaseUrl + QUERY_STRING_BASE + dateStr;
    }

}
```

I think there must be something fundamentally wrong with my design.

Comment: You could use a varargs signature right from the start: `String prepareUrl( T... input );`

Comment: Looks like a Twitter API client to me :-) Anyway... In OO, operations are not defined by their names but by WHAT THEY DO. In your scenario, prepareUrl does different things in different classes. The solution is to give the two methods different names to distinguish between their operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think there must be something fundamentally wrong with my design.

The only thing wrong is that you are trying to conflate a one argument method and a zero argument method.  You just can't do it in Java ... without opening the door to other problems.

Basically you've got three choices:

- Stick with your current approach and explicitly pass `null` in the Void case.
- Add a second (no argument) method to the interface to deal with the Void case, and make it call the one argument method with a `null`.  Your code needs to cope with a `null` when `T` is not `Void`, but it did anyway.
- Refactor the interfaces so that there are two distinct interfaces, one with a `String prepareUrl()` and the other with `String prepareUrl(T)`, and implement the former as a special case class.

Personally, options 2 is slightly better than option 1, but the 3rd option is probably going to lead to other problems; e.g. that particular method with its two variants will be an impediment to polymorphic method calls over the entire space of `T` types.

(Varargs is a bad idea, because that opens the door for *multiple* arguments which is probably meaningless for your problem.)

Answer (score 2):

The question is if `SchedulePageUrlGenerator` really *is* a `UrlGenerator`.  If it has different arguments then I would argue that it is not.  If you have optional arguments to your interface then I guess in the calling code you have to do something like:

```
// this is not a good pattern
if (urlGenerator instanceof SchedulePageUrlGenerator) {
    (SchedulePageUrlGenerator)urlGenerator.prepareUrl();
} else {
    urlGenerator.prepareUrl(...);
}
```

This does seem to be a hack.

All this said, if you have more methods to your interface and only the `prepareUrl(...)` is different then I see no problems with passing in `null` as the `Void` argument to `prepareUrl(...)`.  I guess I would need to see more of the calling framework to understand how you generate the argument and why a `null` argument is such a problem.

One other alternative, again if you have more methods in your interface, is to have *both* with and without argument prepare methods:

```
String prepareUrl( T input );
String prepareUrlNoInput();
```

Then you can throw `UnsupportedOperationException` depending on which is supported by which implementation.  But again, if you have to do something like the `instanceof` `if` statement above, then I think the `null` argument is better.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to value different numbers of arguments for different implementations.

The closest you can get to this is to use a varargs

```
interface UrlGenerator<T> {
    String prepareUrl(T... input );
}


// can use
System.out.println(new StaticUrlGenerator("url").prepareUrl());

//or
System.out.println(new StaticUrlGenerator("url").prepareUrl(null));
```